# cython: memory view of ndarray of strings (or direct ndarray indexing)

Tags: python, numpy, cython

How does one specify a memory view of a ndarray that contains strings?

`char[:]`, `char*[:]`, ... do not work.

To illustrate, my problem is the definition of function `abc(...)`:

```
cdef void abc(char[:] in_buffer):
    cdef char * element
    element = address(in_buffer[1])
    ...

def main():
    cdef Py_ssize_t i, n = 100

    a = np.array(['ABC', 'D', 'EFGHI'])
    for i in range(n):
        abc(a)
```

If a memoryview is not possible, can I implement direct array access myself? I need to avoid the GIL for function `abc(...)`.

---

**Edit 1:** In response to Bi Rico's answer.

My aim is to release the GIL for function `abc(...)` and within it process the string elements of `ndarray in_buffer` with c string-functions. I.e. something like the following:

```
cdef void abc(char[:, ::1] in_buffer) nogil:
    cdef int max_elt_length = in_buffer.shape[1]+1
    cdef char element[max_elt_length+1]
    cdef int length

    for i in range(in_buffer.shape[0]+1):  # is this equivalent to in_buffer.dtype.itemsize + 1 ?
       element[max_elt_length] = 0   # add null-terminator for full-size elements
       memcpy(element, address(buffer[i, 0]), max_length)
       length = strlen(element)
       ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that numpy array dtypes have to have a fixed size. When you make an array of "strings" you're actually making an array of fixed length char arrays. Try this:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array(["cat", "in", "a", "hat"])
array[2] = "Seuss"
print(array)
# ['cat' 'in' 'Seu' 'hat']
print(array.dtype)
# dtype('|S3')
print(array.dtype.itemsize)
# 3
```

With that in mind, you could something like this:

```
cdef void abc(char[:, ::1] in_buffer):
    cdef char * element
    element = address(in_buffer[1, 0])
```

Then when you pass your arrays to `abc` you'll need to do something like:

```
a = np.array(['ABC', 'D', 'EFGHI'])
array_view = a.view('uint8').reshape(a.size, a.dtype.itemsize)
abc(array_view)
```

This is only one approach, but it's the one I would recommend without knowing more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was trying to keep my question general to avoid distracting from my real issue. To answer your question: I am trying to process the string elements of the ndarray with c string functions in a for loop. I edited my question with an additional explanation. Would you mind checking whether I haver correctly applied your suggested technique? Could you also point me to the docs where the `::1` part of the `char[:, ::1]` memoryview definition is explained?

Comment: [The `::1` means that the input buffer should be c contiguous](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#c-and-fortran-contiguous-memoryviews). Your updated code looks right in principle but you have a few off-by-one errors. I think it should be `range(in_buffer.shape[0])` and `max_elt_length = in_buffer.shape[1]`. Finally `in_buffer` has no `dtype` attribute. `in_buffer.shape[0]` is the number of strings in your original array.

Comment: Thanks for the help; I now managed to get my function working.