# cython - Manipulating strings from numpy array

Tags: string, numpy, cython, memoryview

I have problems to generate a memory view on a numpy array containing strings.
The ultimate goal is to convert strings into integers. Inbetween I have to split the string at appropriate places using the c-function `strtok` which takes a pointer as its arguments. Therefore, I cannot simply pass the element from the numpy array, but have to create a memory view as described [here](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#pass-data-from-a-c-function-via-pointer).

Here is my code

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython 

from libc.string cimport strtok
from libc.stdlib cimport strtod, atoi 

DTYPE = np.int
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t

def str2int(string_array):

    if not string_array.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS']:
        string_array = np.ascontiguousarray(string_array)        

    cdef:
        int n = string_array.shape[0]
        char[::1] arr_memview = string_array
        char *token      
        np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] integer_time = np.zeros(n, dtype=DTYPE)
        np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] conv = np.array([60**2, 60, 1], dtype=DTYPE)
        int count, num 
        size_t i

    for i in range(n):

        token = strtok(&arr_memview[i], ':')

        count = 0
        num = 0
        while token!=NULL:
            num += atoi(token)*conv[count] 
            count +=1 
            token = strtok(NULL, ':')

        integer_time[i] = num

    return integer_time
```

The pxy-file compiles, but when I try to use it like this

```
import numpy as np
from strings_to_integers import str2int

strarr = np.array(['00:00:01','00:09:30'], dtype=str)
converted = str2int(strarr)
```

I get an error for the line `char[::1] arr_memview = string_array`:  `ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected end but got a string`.
(There might be further errors down the road.)

I think the answer to my problem is somehow provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774096/cython-memory-view-of-ndarray-of-strings-or-direct-ndarray-indexing), but I do not quite understand it well enough to get my code to work. E.g. when I change the problematic line to `char[:,::1] arr_memview = string_array` and change the first line in the loop to `token = strtok(&arr_memview[i,0], ':')` I receive the error `ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 2, got 1)`.

Comment: Are you on Python2 or Python3? When on python3, using `dtype=str`  will result in unicode, but on python2 in chars. From your code it is obvious, that you expect chars. Use `dtype=np.string_` to get it also on Python3.

Comment: Actually, the answer you have linked explains pretty good what is going on and it consists of more than "just use `char[:,::1]`", it actually also views the data as 2d-array.

Comment: There is also a problem with using `strtok`: it assumes the input to be a NUL-terminated C string, but "strings" in numpy arrays are not NUL-terminated AFAIK. So even if it built, the program would yield strange results and most probably crash. I think this part makes your question not a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: thanks for the input. although I still do not understand all the details of the problem (especially about the dimensionality of the string_array), I managed to get it work by changing the ``arr_memview`` line to ``char *arr_memview = string_array.data`` and then the ``token`` line to ``token = strtok(arr_memview[i*8:(i+1)*8],':')``.