# Fastest approach for iteration over iterable with elements of 16 bytes in cython

Tags: byte, cython, uuid

I have a list of `bytes` in python and I would like to iterate over the list and find the first occurrence of a particular `byte` sequence `q`.

I wanted to use a numpy array but element types in a numpy array or native python array seem to be capped to 64 bits. I have no need to use a python `list` as input to the function. Is there another iterable that can make the cython code faster?

I have the following code

```
        01: cimport cython
        02: 
        03: @cython.boundscheck(False)
        04: @cython.wraparound(False)
>>>>>>>>05: cpdef int index_cython(list uuids, bytes q):
        06:     cdef:
        07:         int pos = 0, k = 0
>>>>>>>>08:         int n_uuids = len(uuids)
        09:         bytes u
        10: 
        11:     for k in range(n_uuids):
>>>>>>>>12:         u = uuids[k]
>>>>>>>>13:         if u == q:
        14:             return pos
        15:         else:
        16:             pos = pos +1
        17: 
        18:     raise ValueError
```

where the `>>>>>>>>` lines are shown in yellow in the annotated code produced by cython, hinting python interactions.

- How can I avoid python interaction at line 12, 13 and 5?
- Can I use a memoryview to do this? (if so, how?)
- Can I leverage the fact that every element has a fixed size of 16 bytes?

Answer (score 1):

There is `list.index`, which under the hood is written C and one would superficially assume one cannot beat that.  But as shown bellow, a speed of 10-20 is possible by utilizing numpy and cython.

Let's establish the baseline:

```py
# create data set:
N=10**6
data = [format(i,'016d').encode() for i in range(N)]
key = data[N-1]

# measure running time
%timeit data.index(key) # 16.7 ms ± 789 µs
```

But there is room for improvement. First, we know that all elements are bytes (or at least element we are searching for), so we don't need to invoke the dynamic dispatch - a costly machinery which would be able to compare instances of all classes. It is quite easy to do it with Cython - actually your version of `index_cython` is already doing it:

```py
%timeit index_cython(data, key)  # 8.35 ms ± 216 µs
```

twice as fast! The reason is, that variable `key` is typed as `bytes` and thus `u==q` can use a special version `__Pyx_PyBytes_Equals` instead of generic and slower `PyObject_RichCompare`.

Now, one can see in the C-file, that the yellow line in the for-loop is due to check, that the object isn't `None`:

```
if (unlikely(__pyx_v_uuids == Py_None)) {
      PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable");
      __PYX_ERR(0, 11, __pyx_L1_error)
    }
```

this can be avoided, by making the check once and not in every iteration, by typing the function-declaration as:

```py
   def int index_cython_2(list uuids not None, bytes q):
      ...
```

by adding the `not None` one shifts the check to the beginning of the function, where it happens only once. This version is somewhat faster:

```
%timeit index_cython_2(data, key)  # 7.88 ms ± 194 µs
```

Another (common) issue with Python objects is their memory layout: They have some memory overhead  - like `PyObject_VAR_HEAD` - and even being next to each other in the list could mean that the addresses where the actual data is saved are far apart, which would lead to many cache misses.

The way our list was created actually leads to bytes object being next to each other in memory (this is an implementation detail of CPython), to really see the effect we can shuffle the list first:

```py
import random
sh_data = list(data)
random.shuffle(sh_data)
sh_key=sh_data[N-1]

%timeit index_cython_2(sh_data, sh_key) # 50.4 ms ± 2.05 ms
```

the impact of cache misses: about 6 times slower!

As we know all elements are 16 byte long, we could use numpy arrays to fix the issue with fragmented memory:

```py
sh_data_as_np = np.array(sh_data)

%timeit np.where(sh_data==sh_key)[0][0] # 8.4 ms ± 185 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

`sh_data_as_np` is of type  `|S16`, which means continuous memory were every 16 bytes (without trailing `\0`) are one element. We are back to the old performance, independent of the order of elements.

However, `np.where` doesn't short-cut and runs through the whole array even if the first element is the one we a looking for. Let's once again use Cython to improve on it ([this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28777163/5769463) is used for accessing the data):

```py
%%cython
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np
from libc.string cimport memcmp


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def search_cython_c( np.uint8_t[::1] data, np.uint8_t[::1] key):
    cdef int size = len(key)
    cdef int n = len(data)//size
    cdef int i
    for i in range(n):
        if memcmp(<void*>&key[0], <void*>&data[i*size], size) == 0:
            return i
    raise ValueError
```

and now:

```py
%timeit search_cython_c(sh_data_as_np.view(np.uint8), np.array([sh_data[N-1]]).view(np.uint8))  # 4.1 ms ± 148 µs
%timeit search_cython_c(sh_data_as_np.view(np.uint8), np.array([sh_data[N//2]]).view(np.uint8))  # 2.15 ms ± 118 µs
```

as one can see, the element from the middle is found twice as fast than the element from the end (which is good) and even the worst case is 2 times faster than numpy version (even better!). It is hard to tell why cython outperforms numpy here, probably due to better optimization of the c-code.

It is still not the end: one could use parallelization or try to improve on `memcmp` by utilizing, that there are always 16 bytes to compare.

Comment: Awesome explanation, thanks a lot! I tried though `index_cython_2` of the form `cpdef int index_cython_2(list uuids not None, bytes q):
` but got `.ipython/cython/_cython_magic_c74b1c61a42ba5a4a8afdf7390136595.pyx:5:25: 'not None' only allowed in Python functions`.  I am using Cython version '0.29.28'

Comment: @DavidBuchaca true it was a typo. It should be `def` and not `cpdef`.